# I want to print the 10 highest probability predictions for my k-NN (not just the indexes of said values)

Tags: python, numpy, knn

I used this code so far, but argsort produces the indexes rather than the value.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

kNN = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 3)
kNN = kNN.fit(X_train,y_train.values.ravel())
probs = kNN.predict_proba(X_test)
best_n = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[:,-10:]
```

I am predicting article id numbers, so I basically want the 10 best article recommendations for each customer.

An example of the output would be:

| Customer_id | Article_id Pred |
| --- | --- |
| 2a3c236907d | 673531001 |

But I would like the top 10 article predictions, so for example:

| Customer_id | Article_id Pred |
| --- | --- |
| 2a3c236907d | 673531001 464277014 108775044 108775051 .... |

Comment: Can we have some little more context on what you use ? Maybe a minimal reproducible example and the library you used

Comment: As far as I understand, you used scikit-learn with a KNclassifier and the use of numpy with axis=1 indicates you want for each element of X_test the max(?) probability value for  all classes